# How to set few UILabel position under each another UILabel position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have 3 labels in UIView and I would like to set label position same as position as below:-

```
Label 1
Label 2
Label 3
```

Now i used

```
label1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,Width,Height); //for 1st label
label2.frame = CGRectMake(0,label1.frame.size.height,Width,Height); 
//for 2nd label which is correct.

label3.frame = CGRectMake(0,label2.frame.size.height,Width,Height); 
//But when i set like this, position will not show correctly. Any idea??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also consider Y position

```
label2.frame = CGRectMake(0,label1.frame.origin.y + label1.frame.size.height,Width,Height); 

label3.frame = CGRectMake(0,label2.frame.origin.y + label2.frame.size.height,Width,Height);
```

Suggestion : Use Stackview

Comment: Thanks alot, I get what I want!

Comment: @Test87 Glad that solution worked !! And also check Stckview as I suggest and Please mark my answer as accepted  if You would not mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (You have to calculate both button `height` and set 3rd label y position  = label1 + label2 `height`)

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,60)]; //for 1st label];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,label1.frame.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,60)];
UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,label1.frame.size.height + label2.frame.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,60)];

NSLog(@"Label 1 Frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(label1.frame));
NSLog(@"Label 2 Frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(label2.frame));
NSLog(@"Label 3 Frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(label3.frame));
```

**Output**

> Label 1 Frame = {{0,0}, {320, 60}}
>   Label 2 Frame = {{0, 60}, {320,60}}
>   Label 3 Frame = {{0, 120}, {320, 60}}